# How did Dexter get away with his plan in the airport?

Tags: plot-explanation, dexter

In the return of the series for Season 7, Dexter is obviously frustrated with what is going on in his life.

In order to deal with his stress, he finds a new victim to prey upon `Doing what I do best`.

He captures his victim in a Miami Airport and takes him into a baggage claim area to perform the deed and uses a surf board bag to carry his body out of the airport to finish the disposal process.

However, knowing how strict US airports have been recently (for foreigners, you essentially get an hour questioning for a toothbrush, if you look at the Security officials the wrong way), how is he able to not only get needles through security, but remains unseen during his whole stalking and abducting of the target?  Or is this just meant for the viewer to suspend reality for this series of events?

Comment: He explains away the needles as being diabetic, no?

Answer (score 10):

I thought he said something about they only care where you are going not where you came from. So they will check you over numerous times to get in but to leave they don't really give much attention.

Comment: They pay attention if you're on an international flight! But yes, for domestic flights you can often practically walk off the plane and into the parking lot.

Answer (score 2):

**Plausible**

1. Needles through TSA

> TSA agent: Wait, sir. What are these for?

> Dexter: Diabetes. I have a prescription if you wanna see it.

> TSA agent: Go ahead.

From [TSA.gov](https://www.tsa.gov/travel/security-screening/whatcanibring/items/unused-syringes):

> Unused syringes are allowed when accompanied by injectable medication. You must declare these items to security officers at the checkpoint for inspection. We recommend, but do not require, that your medications be labeled to facilitate the security process.

2. Exiting (WITHOUT a body) after checking in and going through TSA

I can't find definitive information on MIA (Miami International Airport) but generally at US airports, you can always leave the airport unquestioned even after checking in and going through TSA (provided you are not leaving with a body on a stretcher).

---

**Not plausible**

3. Viktor fails to get on plane after checking in at the airport and going through TSA security.

Airport security camera footage will have Viktor walking into a toilet, Dexter following him in, Dexter injecting him with something in the toilet, Dexter wheeling him out on a wheelchair unconscious, etc.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Viktor is later a suspect---see e.g. S07E05:

> Angel Batista: Deb, I still think Viktor Baskov killed Mike Anderson and Viktor just disappeared into thin air.

Angel is a sufficiently competent investigator who would have easily found the above airport camera footage.

4. Spending significant time (at least an hour?) undisturbed at "Okhotsk Air Unclaimed Baggage" room setting up, killing, and cleaning up

[image]

[image]

Again, even if Dexter is sufficiently lucky to be undisturbed this entire time, all of the above will be captured with cameras.

5. Exiting the airport WITH a body on a stretcher

The only images we are shown after the above kill room images are of Dexter at an airport car park transferring the body to his car (again, all would be captured on camera):

[image]

[image]

We are not shown how Dexter gets out of the airport with a body on a stretcher. It is not plausible that Dexter managed to do this.